# Replicating in pytorch https://www.d2l.ai/chapter_linear-networks/linear-regression-scratch.html

Tags: pytorch, linear-regression, autograd

I am trying to replicate the code in pytorch. However I am having some problems with the autograd function. I am having the following runtime error.

RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time

The code is the following:

```py
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # Assuming the number of examples can be divided by the batch size, all
    # the examples in the training data set are used once in one epoch
    # iteration. The features and tags of mini-batch examples are given by X
    # and y respectively
    for X, y in data_iter(batch_size, features, labels):
        print (X)
        print (y)
        l = loss(net(X,w,b) , y)
        print (l)
        l.backward(retain_graph=True)
        print (w.grad)
        print (b.grad)

        with torch.no_grad():
          w -= w.grad * 1e-5/batch_size
          b -= b.grad * 1e-5/batch_size 
          w.grad.zero_()
          b.grad.zero_()
```

Can someone explain how the autograd works in python? If someone can recommend me a good resource on learning pytorch that will be great.

Comment: You forgot to post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Pytorch is quite different from Tensorflow by its dynamic computational graph. To save the memory, Pytorch will delete all intermediate nodes in the grpah once they are no longer used. That is, you will face troubles if you want to backprop your gradients through these intermediate nodes twice or more.

The simple solution would be setting `retain_graph=True`. For example,

```
model = Autoencoder()
rec = model(x)
loss_1 = mse_loss(rec, x)
loss_2 = l1_loss(rec, x)

opt.zero_grad()
loss_1.backward(retain_graph=True)
loss_2.backward()
opt.step()
```